# css div height fill to screen size

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div and want to last div height will fill.
I try somethings but didnt work.

```
<div class="maincontent">
    <div class="patient_info"></div>
    <div class="patient_buttons"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-8" style="padding-right:0;">
            <div class="bg_tooths"></div>
            <div class="treatment_list_bg">
                <div class="treatment_list_banner"></div>
                <div class="treatment_list"></div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Codes:[css codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2nKd.jpg)

[image]

It is will be fit to screen size. But I could not do it. Maybe it is easy but I am new in css. Can you help me?

Comment: Take a look at answer and tell us if it was OK. @kamil kunt

Comment: can you please add css code?

Comment: I already add but format image.  You can look on there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2nKd.jpg

Comment: Getting an html element to take 100% height is legendary difficult! But, with the introduction of CSS flexbox and grid this has become quite easy: cf. https://css-tricks.com/boxes-fill-height-dont-squish + https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-holy-grail-layout

Answer (score 0):

this html:

```
<div class="maincontent">
  <div class="patient_info child"></div>
  <div class="patient_buttons child"></div>
  <div class="row child">
    <div class="col-xl-8" style="padding-right:0;">
        <div class="bg_tooths"></div>
        <div class="treatment_list_bg">
            <div class="treatment_list_banner"></div>
            <div class="treatment_list"></div>
        </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

then use jquery:

```
$('.child').last().css("height", screen.Height);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "calc" and viewport size (vh) in css:

```
height: calc(100vh - 50px - 5rem);
```

Where 100vh stands for the vertical size of the viewport. We subtract every single height of our other divs (you should include their paddings, margins and border *Y* sizes aswell).

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Jasqui/pen/JwoXjB)

- [Css calc() in w3school along with its compatibility chart](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp)
- [Here you can read more about vh and other CSS units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)